# Can a user whose account is suspended due to voting irregularities comment on his answer to my question?

Tags: discussion, support, comment, privileges, account-suspension

I asked a few questions long time ago and couldn't see the answer to them due to being critically ill. Now on some answers the answerer's reputation is  changed to 1 and it is written on his account that: "This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities."

> Question: I am not able to understand completely that user's answer. So, as usual I asked in comments for more details. But Can he see my comments? Can he reply to them? Can he edit his answers?

Kindly shed some light on this issue!

Comment: This feature request on [meta.se] is a bit related: [When my account is suspended and I'm addressed in a comment, please notify the user that I cannot respond](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62743). It is marked ([meta-tag:status-declined]).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The suspended user, she or he, cannot respond to comments.  They have read-only access. They can see your comments, but cannot comment, nor can they edit any of their answers.  They can do nothing except read what is on the site, until the suspension expires.